# vim easymotion can only paste the first character of the clipboard

Tags: vim

in my vimrc

```
map / <Plug>(easymotion-sn)\v\c
```

but when I want to search something, I copy it with `y` command or `command + c`, then I want to paste it, but only paste the first character

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with that mapping, specifically the `\v\c` part?

Comment: \v:use the magic which can use regex  \c: search case-insensitvely , even if I delete \v\c, it also doesn't work

Comment: So that's an issue with the plugin itself. Use its issue tracker.

Comment: I know, I made the issue https://github.com/easymotion/vim-easymotion/issues/348, but nobody answered me， so I come here